# How to put border around the div by class name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is my html file with multiple div and I am looking to put blue border in each div element

```html
<div class="myDiv">
<p><span style="color: #00bcf4;"><strong>1) <u>Units of Measurement</u></strong></span></p>
<p><strong><em>@ K</em></strong><em>ing &nbsp;<strong>H</strong>ector&nbsp; <strong>D</strong>ied &nbsp;<strong>M</strong>ysteriously&nbsp;<strong>D</strong>rinking&nbsp;</em></p>
<span style="color: #0000ff;"><strong>&nbsp; &nbsp;K</strong>ilo&nbsp;&nbsp;<strong>H</strong>ecto&nbsp; &nbsp;<strong>D</strong>eka &nbsp;<strong>M</strong>eter&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <strong>D</strong>eci&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p><strong><em>C</em></strong><em>hoklate&nbsp;<strong>M</strong>ilk</em></p>
<span style="color: #0000ff;"><strong>C</strong>enti&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Milli</span>
<p>&hellip;&hellip;&hellip;&hellip;&hellip;&hellip;&hellip;&hellip;&hellip;&hellip;&hellip;&hellip;&hellip;&hellip;&hellip;&hellip;&hellip;&hellip;&hellip;&hellip;&hellip;&hellip;</p>
</div>

<div class="myDiv">

<p><span style="color: #00bcf4;"><strong><u>2) Tens ' Multipliers</u></strong></span></p>
<p><strong><em>@ D</em></strong><em>esi&nbsp;</em>&nbsp; &nbsp;<strong><em>H</em></strong><em>ero</em>&nbsp;&nbsp;<strong><em>K</em></strong><em>illed&nbsp;<strong>M</strong>ega&nbsp;<strong>G</strong>igantic&nbsp;<strong>T</strong>errorists</em></p>
<span style="color: #0000ff;"><strong>&nbsp;&nbsp; D</strong>ekka&nbsp;&nbsp;<strong>H</strong>ecto &nbsp;<strong>K</strong>ilo&nbsp;&nbsp;<strong>M</strong>ega&nbsp;&nbsp;<strong>G</strong>iga&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<strong>T</strong>era</span>
<p>&nbsp; &nbsp;10<sup>1</sup>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;10<sup>2</sup>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;10<sup>3</sup>&nbsp; &nbsp;10<sup>6</sup>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;10<sup>9</sup>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;10<sup>12</sup></p>
<p>&hellip;&hellip;&hellip;&hellip;&hellip;&hellip;&hellip;&hellip;&hellip;&hellip;&hellip;&hellip;&hellip;&hellip;&hellip;&hellip;&hellip;&hellip;&hellip;&hellip;&hellip;</p>
</div>
```

I tried to do with this but it didn't work

```js
<script>
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementByClassName("myDiv").style.border = "thick solid #0000FF";
}

</script>

<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Set border</button>
```

Also I would like to set the function to load automatically when the page loads.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Run your function when page loads is as easy as:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function myFunction() {
            document.getElementByClassName("myDiv").style.border = "thick solid #0000FF";
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="myFunction();">

    </body>
</html>
```

And for the border (using JavaScript):

```
document.getElementsById("myDiv").style.border = "thick solid #0000FF";
```

Warning for that getElement**s**ById

Answer (score 1):

Why do you not use CSS?

```
.myDiv{
    border: thick solid #0000ff;
}
```

Or if you need to use JS, use

```
document.querySelectorAll('.myDiv').forEach( div => {
    div.style.border = 'thick solid #0000ff';
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var myDivs=document.getElementsByClassName("myDiv");
for(var i=0; i<myDivs.length;i++){
    myDivs[i].style.border = "thick solid #0000FF";
}
```

Remember that `getElementByClassName` does'nt exist. `getElementsByClassName` returns you a HTML Collection of all divs with the class.

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery to set border of each element in a div
 (in my case p is an element of div)

```
     <div class="mydiv">
      <p>test1</p>
      <p>test2</p>
      <p>test3</p>
      </div>

      <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
      $(".mydiv p").css('border','1px solid red')
      });
     </script>
```